# Confused about vertical scrollbar of body tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have read about `DOOM clientWidth Property` and `DOM offsetWidth Property` on w3schools

> The clientWidth property returns the viewable width of an element in pixels, including padding, but not the border, scrollbar or margin.
>   The offsetWidth property returns the viewable width of an element in pixels, including padding, border and scrollbar, but not the margin.

I understand clearly both of them, but when I access any website which has vertical scrollbar, open developer console then add `document.body.clientWidth` and `document.body.offsetWidth`, both give same result. I wonder whether this scrollbar is windows's scrollbar, but when I add css `body{overflow:hidden}` , it works and I think this scrollbar is body's scrollbar 
Can anyone help me understand why 2 above property give same result ?
Thank you

Comment: `body` is a special element, i can't tell you what's really going on in there because i don't know and i haven't looked it up, However if you try the same thing with a normal element you'll get the expected results   https://jsfiddle.net/y2azjhoe/

Comment: You're basically right. The scrollbar belongs to the viewport, not the body element. `body{overflow:hidden}`is also being propagated to the viewport from the body element.

Comment: @Alohci So where is body scroll's bar, Is body's scrollbar and windows's scrollbar are coincident ?? Thanks You

Comment: You can force body to have its own scrollbar, if you assign a non-visible overflow to  the <html> element and scroll or auto overflow to the <body> element. See https://jsbin.com/hiselikite/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: @Alohci I got it, thanks for your very clear answer.